# Why is Star Fleet located in Cailfornia

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-command

Why is Star fleet headquarters in  San Francisco California, instead of New York city  or Lyon France ?  United Nations or Interpol represent international functions somewhat reflective of the Federation of Planets. San Francisco seems unlikely to be a historical and symbolic choice for the representation of unity of  the earth. The UN and Interpol and it's geographical sites and purpose would serve as a better memory of Unity.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29099/why-is-starfleet-hq-in-san-francisco

Comment: Welcome to the SF&F site! Your question is a good question, +1. I looks like this is a duplicate of another question already asked by another user. Duplicates are not a bad thing, but in order to avoid this happening a lot you can try to search around before asking to see if it's already been asked. Also see the [tour] and the [help]. :)